# Passing functions with State variable to Child View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass different functions to child view. For that I use `typalias` and different initialisers.

I get an Error when I try to pass a `@State`-variable. How do I need to set the `Binding`-variable in the child view?

Error is as follows:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'Binding'

Here is my code:

```swift
typealias OnTabHandler = (String) -> Void

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var onTabHandler:OnTabHandler = { text in
        print(text)
    }

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            // print to console
            ChildView(text: "Hello", onTabHandler: onTabHandler)

            // show sheet
            ChildView()
                .sheet(isPresented:$showSheet){ Text("sheet view")}
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView:View{
    var text:String
    var onTabHandler:OnTabHandler
    var showSheet:Binding<Bool>

    // print to console
    init(text:String, onTabHandler:@escaping OnTabHandler){
        self.text = text
        self.onTabHandler = onTabHandler
        self.showSheet = Binding.constant(false)
    }

    // show sheet
    init(showSheet:Binding<Bool>){
        self.showSheet = showSheet
        self.onTabHandler = {_ in

            // Error here
            self.showSheet = true
        }
        self.text = ""
    }

    var body: some View{
        Button("Tab Me"){
            self.onTabHandler(self.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is struct, you cannot use `self` in such case, because it would be actually trying to copy value which construction is not finished yet... instead you can use binding directly because binding actually a holder of reference, so correct & worked approach in your case is

```
self.onTabHandler = {_ in

    showSheet.wrappedValue = true
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Is it somehow possible to access the `managedObjectContext` like this when I get this from the `@Environment`? Apparently, `wrappedValue` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

See below for the two constructors.

Tip: Using .constant is only considered acceptable during prototyping. I will look for the apple reference but it is mentioned here under "Prototype with constant bindings" https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks

```
import SwiftUI

typealias OnTabHandler = (String) -> Void

struct PassingFunc: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var onTabHandler: OnTabHandler = { text in
        print(text)
    }

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            // print to console
            ChildView(text: "Hello - Console", showSheet:$showSheet, onTabHandler: onTabHandler)

            // show sheet
            ChildView(text: "Hello - Present"
                , showSheet:$showSheet, onTabHandler: {_ in
                self.showSheet = true}
            )
                .sheet(isPresented:$showSheet){ Text("sheet view")}
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView:View{
    var text:String
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    var onTabHandler:OnTabHandler

    var body: some View{
        Button("Tab Me"){
            self.onTabHandler(self.text)
        }
    }
}
```